# angular-perfect-scrollbar | update, scroll to bottom, or alternative

Tags: angularjs, scroll, scrollbar

I just installed [angular-perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/itsdrewmiller/angular-perfect-scrollbar).
I used the jQuery perfect-scrollbar Plugin but since angular it was thrown out.

Question:

- is there a way to update the angular-perfect-scrollbar like `$('#container').perfectScrollbar('update');` in jQuery ?
- how can I scroll to bottom of container (on content change) with that angular plugin?

If thats not possible with this angular plugin are there alternatives that includes the features above ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as I tested, you need to add  `<include-padding='true'>` to html tag then it could scroll to bottom(in fact this will change the scroller length, therefore)

it looks like

```
<perfect-scrollbar include-padding='true'>
  <..your stuff..>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

cheers